# Vue.js element reference on attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following code:

```html
<input type="text"
       @input="disableField($event.target)"
       :disabled="isFieldDisabled(????)"
/>
```

I want to pass to the isFieldDisabled method the same value which I get in $event.target - the element reference. I cannot find the way how to do this. I know that I could use the :ref but in this case I need to do it as shown above.

This is only the example use case. I know that to disable the field I can do it better but I want to show the problem in simplest way.

Comment: You can not find a way to do it because you are doing it wrong way. Vue is data driven, not DOM driven. Create a variable in data that holds the disabled state and use that variable in template

Comment: @MichalLevý the "disable" is only an example (as I described above). I need to find a way how to set the argument using function which gets the current html element as an argument.

Comment: You can do it for more things than `disable` with Vue too.

Comment: I understand that "disabled" is example. That does not change the fact that you are trying to use Vue in a way it was not designed and ignoring the way it was designed for - to be a data drive view controller. Your life will be considerably easier if you try to understand that and change the approach

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible the way you're asking for it.

- The way that Vue works with VNodes, the element won't exist the first time you try to evaluate `disabled`: Vue evaluates the properties to determine how the DOM *should* look and then creates the elements to match. As [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html):

  > Note that you can only access the ref **after the component is mounted**. If you try to access `input` in a template expression, it will be `null` on the first render. This is because the element doesn't exist until after the first render!
- With async components, the attributes will need to have well-defined values even if there isn't a Component to render yet, let alone well-defined elements to position there.
- With fragment components, there won't ever be a single HTML element to interact with, because the component represents multiple top-level HTML elements.

Events don't have to play by the same rules, because you're defining handlers: DOM events will come from one source and apply to one target, and absent components don't emit events. Even then, the syntax gives you access to `$event`, not to an `$el` for a direct element reference.

The most straightforward way is to use a `ref` to get to the object after Vue creates it, subject to the same null-on-first-render `ref` rules above. If you need to pass a handle into a multipurpose method in the shape of  `getFoo(argument)` your argument may have to be a string or enum key you define, not the element itself.